# display data from the column where designation == "manager"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

i have three models as followings.check out wheather i have associated them correctly.sorry.am new to rails

```
  class Designation < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :employes
  end


  class Employe < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :designation
     has_many :branch
  end



  class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employe
  end
```

in my employe form i have added a select box to choose designations .and displayed in employes index page... now the problem is i want to display the name of employes which have thier designation as manager in my branch model..how to do that.....
this is my branch controller

```
    def index
      @branches = Branch.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
    @branch = Branch.new
    end
```

and this is my branches view

```
      <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Branch name</th>
                        <th>Branch address</th>
                        <th>Phoneno</th>
                         <th>Mangers name</th>
                         <th>Status</th>                                 
                        <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                          <tbody>
                                <% @branches.each do |branch| %>
                              <tr>

                                    <td><%= branch.branch_name %></td>
                                    <td><%= branch.branch_address %></td>
                                    <td><%= branch.phoneno %></td>
                                    <td><%= branch.employe_id %></td>

                                      </div>
                                      <td></td>
                                      <td>
                  <% if branch.is_active == true %>
                <%= link_to " Active ",edit_branch_path(branch),class:   
                   "btn btn-warning"%>
                <%else%><%= link_to
                      "Inactive",edit_branch_path(branch),class: "btn 
                      btn-warning"%>
                  <%end%>

                   </td>
                   <td> 
             <div class="btn-group">
            <span class=" btn btn-info dropdown-toggle"
             data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu1">Action
            <b class="caret"></b>
              </span>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_branch_path(branch) %></li>
         <li><%= link_to 'Destroy', branch, method: :delete, data: {
           confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></li>
           </ul>
          </li> 
           </td>
        </div>
       </tr>
       <% end %>
        </tbody>
       </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct following association:

```
 class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :employes
 end

 class Employe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :designation
   belongs_to :branch
 end

class Designation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

## views

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Branch name</th>
      <th>Branch address</th>
      <th>Phoneno</th>
      <th>Mangers name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @branches.each do |branch| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= branch.branch_name %></td>
        <td><%= branch.branch_address %></td>
        <td><%= branch.phoneno %></td>
        <% managers = [] %>
        <% branch.employes.each{|e| managers << e.name if e.designation.name == "manager" } %>
        <td><%= managers.uniq %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'designations.employe_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `designations`.* FROM `designations` WHERE `designations`.`employe_id` = 1 LIMIT 1 am getting following error bro.

Comment: may be while creating the employe scaffold i had added designation:references ...is this a reason ..what should i do now?plz help me

Comment: have you added employe_id to designation?

Comment: add employe_id to designation table

Comment: and branch_id in employe table

Comment: yes i have added branch id to employe bt not added employe id yo designation

Comment: <% branch.employes.each{|e| managers << e.title if e.designation.name == "manager" } %> its displaying error on this line as undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: try  
<% branch.employes.each{|e| managers << e.title if e.designation.try(:name) == "manager" } %>

Comment: thanks bro..bt am just  getting an array sign like "[]"in my manager'name column in branch

Comment: and also i lost all my designations from my employes

Comment: undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Do you have a designation as manager in designation table?
If yes, then does it contain employee_id?

Comment: Yes i have designation as Manager (M in capital ).and i have also added employe_id in designation as you told

Comment: then try <% branch.employes.each{|e| managers << e.title if e.designation.try(:name) == "Manager" } %>

Comment: i tried that before still its giving me.undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass

Comment: plz remberber iam getting the designation by using select box in form and i chose it from there in employes table.i used to get it before bt now am not getting even designations in emolyes table

Comment: Is the empploye_name is in title attribute?

Comment: yes iam getting empty arrays bro..and i have title as attribute for designation  and e_name as attribute  for employes name.now i changed the asociation of employe as belongs to designation ...then its now displaying the designation in employes ..what i have to do is directy display the names of employes in branch who are managers.so i dont think there is any neccecity to associate branch and designations as we have it in employes now.is it possible..

Comment: try this as attributes are not correct first,

 <% branch.employes.each{|e| managers << e.e_name if e.designation.try(:title) == "Manager" } %>

Comment: first I fetch employees of one branch then check who is manager and add that employee in managers array.

Comment: i tried that tooo bro.but still not working .. i have a alernative idea bro.. can we make a select box of the employes which are managers in branch from..i think it will do.and we dont have branch in employe we dont need that bro...we only need employe who are manger in employes just we want their names we dont need to add branch id in employes table also...

Comment: You can make a drop down of manager in which list all employee of branch and select manager

Comment: yeah bt iam not able to display only maangers ..all the employes are displayed.in drop down. i changed the association as in Branch as belongs_to :employes to display the select box

Answer (score 0):

I think employee should have one designation, please check the below modified model code,

```
  class Designation < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :employee
  end


  class Employe < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :designation
     has_many :branches
  end



  class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employe
  end
```